# How to use OpenJpa using persistence.xml without using Enhance.xml ..?

Tags: openjpa, persistence.xml

How can I use OpenJpa ,with using Persistence.xml configuration same we use in jpa, I dont want to use Enhance.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rely on some non-IDE tool to build your app, you can enhance automatically during buildtime. For Maven, for example, see [this](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-maven.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a JavaEE container you will get enhancement for free. The other option when running in a JSE environment is to configure the `-javaagent`.

Take a look at the section titled '[Explicit javaagent support'](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html). As for JavaEE stuff, I'd suggest getting ahold of the [Pro JPA 2 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249269). It is very good at describing usage of JPA in an EE environment.

Comment: can U refer me any reference site from where I can understand it properly.